# Why is the div element not spanning the parent's height?

Tags: html, css

I have the following mark up,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        min-height: 98vh;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      #root {
        min-height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Testing.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The div with `#root` id has body as its parent which has a height of `98vh`. The div with `#root` id has a height of `100%` but it is not getting the 100 percent height of body. What am I missing here?

Comment: if given "min-height: 1000px; " it worked. but not sure is correct

Comment: Well yeah, but I want to set the div's height relative to its parent.

Comment: Just use `height` instead of `min-height`.

Comment: use flexbox like shown in the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the full height of a child element based on the parent element.

**Solution 1**

Just use `min-height: inherit;` in child element css, it's use parent's `min-height` value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
      }
      body {
        min-height: 98vh;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      #root {
        min-height: inherit;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Testing.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2**

You can use `height:100%` in chid element if patent have also fix height value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
      }
      body {
        height: 98vh;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      #root {
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Testing.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `height` instead of `min-height`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        height: 98vh;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      #root {
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Testing.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not quite solve the issue, I don't want the body to always be `98vh` for example if there is a lot of text on it, I am okay the body being taller.

The question still stands though, if the parent is indeed 98vh then why does setting its child to a 100% not expand it to 98vh as well?

Comment: Then u can use `min-height` on parent and set the `min-height` for child element **inherit**